Pluto & Tasche Approach to Portfolio Loss Distribution
In the paper Estimating Probabilities of Default for LowDefault Portfolios authors propose methodology for conservative estimation of $pd$ in low default portfolios.
For a given grade they derive left-sided confidence interval $[0, p^*]$ at level $\gamma$ for $pd$ given number of observations and defaults in all grades not better tham analysing one.
As I understand this is equivalent to testing $H_0: pd \geqslant p_0$ against $H_A: pd < p_0$ for some $p_0$ at level of significance $\alpha = 1 - \gamma$. If and only if $p_0 \leqslant p^*$ than $H_0$ is not rejected at level $\alpha$.
In section 5.9 they discuss application of methodology to validation rather than estimation.

First, the low default estimation methodology based on upper conﬁdence bounds has a high degree of inbuilt conservatism. Comparing default rates or PDs estimated by other methodologies against conﬁdence-bound-based PDs must take this estimation bias into account – having observed default rates not breaching our upper confidence bounds should not be regarded as a particular achievement, and observing default rates above the confidence bounds may indicate a serious PD underestimation indeed.

Let suppose I have some externally estimated $pd_{model}$. If $pd_{model} > p^*$ that equivalent that $H_0: pd \geqslant pd_{model}$ should be rejected against $H_A: pd < pd_{model}$ at level $\alpha$.
My question is why authors write that

observing default rates above the confidence bounds may indicate a serious PD underestimation indeed

when we have $H_A: pd < pd_{model}$ which is a PD overestimation?
